# Data not retrieved from the database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new to Android , I want to create application that fetch all the incoming numbers and show in a list.
On installing the application first time it runs but does not show the incoming numbers, when we try to open application again after installing it get crashed.

To run  application after installing ,it require to clear its data(then the application runs but does not show anything)

**logcat**

```
    1-10 11:03:19.141 10244-10244/nischayvaish.com.test1 E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 2 columns.
11-10 11:03:19.141 10244-10244/nischayvaish.com.test1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-10 11:03:19.142 10244-10244/nischayvaish.com.test1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: nischayvaish.com.test1, PID: 10244
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nischayvaish.com.test1/nischayvaish.com.test1.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                            at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:511)
                                                                            at android.database.CursorWindow.getInt(CursorWindow.java:578)
                                                                            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:69)
                                                                            at nischayvaish.com.test1.MainActivity.readFromDb(MainActivity.java:60)
                                                                            at nischayvaish.com.test1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

This is **MainActivity** class

```
  private TextView tv1;
    private RecyclerView recycler_view;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private ArrayList<IncomingNumber> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyTxt);
        recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler_view.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
        recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
        readFromDb();
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                readFromDb();
            }
        };

    }

    private void readFromDb() {
        arrayList.clear();
        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readNumber(database);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String number;
                int id;
                number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.INCOMING_NUMBER));
                id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                arrayList.add(new IncomingNumber(id, number));
            }
            cursor.close();
            dbHelper.close();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DbContract.UPDATE_UI_FILTER));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

This is **DbHelper.class**

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "numberDb";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =2;
    private static final String CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + DbContract.TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + DbContract.INCOMING_NUMBER + " TEXT);";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "drop table if exists " + DbContract.TABLE_NAME;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void saveNumber(String number, SQLiteDatabase database) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DbContract.INCOMING_NUMBER, number);
        Log.e(number,"incoming nuumber");
        database.insert(DbContract.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor readNumber(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String[] projection = {"id", DbContract.INCOMING_NUMBER};
        return (database.query(DbContract.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, null));
    }
```

**DbContract.class**

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "incomingInfo";
    public static final String INCOMING_NUMBER = "incomingNumber";
    public static final String UPDATE_UI_FILTER = "nischayvaish.com.test1.UPDATE_UI";
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.` You cursor doesn't contain a certain column which you are trying to access (I suspect it is `DbContract.INCOMING_NUMBER`). Can you show your `DbContract` Class?

Comment: You need to call moveToFirst before accessing the cursor.

Comment: This is DbContract.class @BernoulliGate

Comment: @GabeSechan S/He already uses `while (cursor.moveToNext()) {`. In facts, the row is **0**, as in `Couldn't read row 0, col -1`. Otherwise, it would have been **row -1**.

Answer (score 0):

Without having done a detailed analysis of your code, the following statement causes the error:

`id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));`

This is because the cursor cannot find a column named `id`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)

> Returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or -1 if the column doesn't exist. If you expect the column to exist use getColumnIndexOrThrow(String) instead, which will make the error more clear.

This, combined with jibrahim's answer that your call to database.query is probably wrong, should lead you to working code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is that the `getColumnIndex` method is case sensitive so instead of using `getColumnIndex("id")`, you should be using `getColumnIndex("ID")`

so your **`readDB`** method could be :-

```
private void readFromDb() {
    arrayList.clear();
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readNumber(database);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String number;
            int id;
            number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.INCOMING_NUMBER));
            id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID")); //<<<<<<<<
            arrayList.add(new IncomingNumber(id, number));
        }
        cursor.close();
        dbHelper.close();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

*Notes*

- ***`//<<<<<<<<***' indicates the changed line
- *You should really close the cursor if the cursor is empty/has 0 rows so really the `cursor.close()` and therefore the `dbHelper.close()` should be outside/after the `if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {....}` construct.*